# Why can't I type in the text field of my IntelliJ plugin's popup?

Tags: java, swing, popup, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to make a simple plugin.  I just want to create a popup that I can type in.  Right now, the popup appears, but I can't focus on it or type in the textfield.  Here is how I am creating the popup.

```
public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
    JTextField myTextField = new JTextField("Here I am", 20);
    JComponent myPanel = new JPanel();
    myPanel.add(myTextField);
    JBPopupFactory.getInstance().createComponentPopupBuilder(myPanel, myTextField).createPopup().show(myPanel);
}
```

To be clear, the popup appears along with it's JPanel and JTextField, but I can't focus on it or type in it.  Also, myPanel.isEditable() returns true.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly the problem was, but I fixed it by creating the popup with this line instead.

```
JBPopupFactory.getInstance().createComponentPopupBuilder(panel, textField).createPopup().showInBestPositionFor(e.getData(PlatformDataKeys.EDITOR));
```

This centered the popup.

Answer (score 0):

by invoking `ComponentPopupBuilder.setRequestFocus(true)` i fixed this problem.